# subsequent call to sql stored procedure very slow

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures, plsql

When I call my stored procedure the first time, it executes in a few seconds. When i call it again, the exact same way, after say a minute or 2, it takes around 3-5 minutes! The stored procedure just does a run-of-the-mill Update with some where clauses, nothing extraordinary.

I have seen other questions here, where stored procedures have run slow the first time and faster the subsequent times, so my situation really puzzles me!

I ran the application in hibernate debug mode, and this is where it seems to take a long time, the second time around : You can see there's a 3 minute gap between the first and the second debug statement

```
........ //binding of other named parameters
17 Sep 2013 17:06:38,287 | DEBUG | org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan [139] | bindNamedParameters() ABC111 -> productName [1]
17 Sep 2013 17:09:39,051 | DEBUG | org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher [418] | about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
```

Here's how i call my stored procedure:

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append("{call ").append(Constants.StoreProcedures.UPDATE_ORDER_STATUS)
     .append("(:productName, :prodNumber, ")
     //other parameters
     .append(")} ");

final String queryStr = query.toString();
Object obj = super.getJpaTemplate().execute(new JpaCallback() {
    public Object doInJpa(EntityManager em) throws PersistenceException {
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryStr);
        query.setParameter("productName", prodBean.getProductName());
        query.setParameter("prodNumber", prodBean.getProdNumber());
        //other parameters
        return query.executeUpdate();
    }
});
```

EDIT:
On sniffing around further, i noticed that between the two calls to the stored proc in question, lets calls it SP1, another stored Proc (SP2) is called in a loop. And i face this problem only if the number of loops is high - over 400. And if i run SP1 after say 5 minutes or so, it seems to run fine - doesn't take so long. (Haven't figured out the actual threshold time gap though, after which the problem doesn't occur.)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres? Did you check the execution plans for the queries inside the procedure?

Comment: I am using oracle. What exactly should i be looking for, when you say i have to check the execution plans?

Comment: Turn on hibernate tracing and see the EXACT SQL being executed.

Comment: Could it be possible that other session has locks on the table you're updating ?

Comment: @OldProgrammer : I enabled the logging of org.hibernate.SQL and just got this : `{call UPDATE_ORDER_STATUS(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )} `

Comment: @user272735 : Hmm, interesting.. After the SP is called the first time to update the table, i send a request to another remote system asynchronously. That remote system updates the same table after a few minutes. Could this affect me in any way?

Comment: Yes it could affect you in the case the procedures are updating the same row at the same time.